# How to increase user session in magento 2.1.10

Tags: magento-2.1

I want to increase my user session in magento 2.1.10 to 4 hours and after 30 min of inactivity that session is closed.
i have in the php.ini this :
session.cookie_lifetime = 14400
session.gc_maxlifetime = 14400
memory_limit = 768M
max_execution_time = 18000
session.auto_start = off

### suhosin.session.cryptua = off

and in my magento admin are the same seconds.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can change session time in Magento Admin itself, you don't need to change your php.ini :

Login to your Magento Admin and change session settings in :

> Stores > System > Configuration > Web > Default Cookie Settings

Also, you will find all information in magento docs, under session and cookies management :

http://docs.magento.com/m2/ce/user_guide/customers/customer-online-options.html